# Android: What does this google analytics dispatcher warning mean?

Tags: android, google-analytics

Im using google analytics to track the user in my android application, but in my log i keep getting warnings like:

```
10-22 14:44:08.879: WARN/googleanalytics(1266): Dispatcher thinks it finished, but there were 56 failed events
```

Anyone knows what the problem can be? Im using a correct account key?

Has somebody solved the problem with this appearing if there are no whitespaces?

Comment: So, really nobody knows how to fix this error ?    10-23 07:55:39.301: WARN/googleanalytics(941): Dispatcher thinks it finished, but there were 93 failed events

Comment: What library are you using? Where'd it come from?

Comment: I'm getting the same error trying to integrate the google analytics mobile library to my android app.

Comment: Same error here with Google Analytics 0.7 for Android and the resulting statistics are definitely not correct.

Comment: Same problem for me.  I verified that there are no whitespaces in my trackPageView calls.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have another app where analytics works fine :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. In my particular case it was because I had some spaces in the event "label" that is a String.

Be sure that all the Strings you are passing to the GoogleAnalytics library are encoded correctly to be a part of the URL that is called to deliver the event/pageview to google.

I was quite surprise the library didn't manage this use case.

Comment: I tried to disable event tracking and still have the problem, only with pageview tracking and no white spaces.

Comment: @Stefan ... ptoblem is that your analytics database is broken i you have ever inserted anything with a whitespace..even a single row... you have to clear those rows...or delete det database by uninstalling your app..

Comment: Thanks PHP_Jedi for the response. I ended up using Flurry, which is in my opinion much better anyway (for mobile analytics).

Comment: If you have problems with a negative number of failed events be sure to open and close the Tracker correct.

Answer (score 1):

i found a reference to people using the iphone lib. 'just delete the app, it will delete the cache'. in our case it means you can delete the `google_analytics.db` in your databases directory. worked for me...

Comment: Hmm... that might work, but how do i delete this table/database when the app is installed on thousands of devices "out there"?